# Relationship between data structures and heap size in java

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, jvm, heap-memory

I am trying to learn the relationship between a data structure and heap size and type of JVM.

- While choosing an algorithm, I have to choose the best data structure suited to my requirement.
- Now lets say that the data given to me is in GBs.

Now I have following questions:

- Will I have to change my heap size changes according to the size of data set provided to me. If yes how?
- How picking a 64 bit over 32 bit can help me in handling huge data provided to me.

I just want to understand that what all factors needs to be analyzed while designing an algorithm. And how many things changes according to the data set size.

Comment: *"Will my heap size changes according to the size of data set provided to me. If yes how?"* That part is unclear. And I think you might have your question backwards. Heap usage depends on your data processing strategy. Not the other way around.

Comment: @the8472  I edited my question, and I just want to understand that if very large data set is provided to me then what can be the constraints and how can I resolve them. Can heap size create an issue. N if yes then can I use 64 bit processor and resolve it???

Comment: I still don't see how that's specific to the JVM? It would just be the same with a C program or any other programming language.

Comment: @the8472 I personally would like to consider the JVM in my mind. As I want to relate heap size, RAM and garbage collector in java. That's why I asked this with reference to JAVA only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need more memory if you need to store more data.  A few GB is unlikely to make much difference unless you have a small machine.

Java uses compressed OOPs up to 64 GB of heap so you don't need 64-bit references unless you need more heap than this.

The main question is whether the data fits in memory or not.  If it fits in memory, you will program it one way, most likely the simplest.  If it doesn't fit in memory, you will need to perform the sorting in pieces and perform a merge sort to combine the sorted portions.

> can I use 64 bit processor and resolve it

I can't imagine why you would use a 32-bit processor if you have large, multi GB amounts of data to process.  You can get 64-bit processors in mobile phones these days.

Comment: " I can't imagine why you would use a 32-bit processor if you have large" : Regarding this, I just want to know that its just a best suggestion to use 64 bit processor or I cannot use 32 bit?. So far I know 32 bit cannot access n deal with  more then 4 gb memory, so even if I get 64 GB of heap size, I need to change my system to 64 bit to access address in memory which is more then 4 gb.. Please correct if my understanding is right ???

Comment: @user3610891 most 32-bit processors cannot have heaps of more than 1.2 GB to 3 GB depending on your OS.  Given you need space to perform operations, a 32-bit processor limits you to about 1 GB.  Another reason to not use 32-bit is they are getting increasing harder to find, even second hand.  I don't know why you would write new code  for a 32-bit JVM unless you were targeting a device.

Comment: @user3610891 If you want 3 - 64 GB of heap you still need a 64-bit processor, however you can use 32-bit references to address this much memory.  For more than 64 GB you need 64-bit references.